# Expected ';' when trying to run excel macro with jscript

Tags: javascript, excel, jscript, object-expected, vba

I am writing a web page to serve as a front to access an excel workbook that generates a config file for some hardware. Currently this is just me testing the concept and getting familiar with how jscript automates excel.

My problem is when I try to run the macro, I keep getting an "Expected ';' error at line 46 Char 7." As far as I am aware the syntax is correct, and it works with a different excel workbook macro. I have already fixed the .dlls on my PC and checked IE settings, but what confuses me is why this won't work yet the other jscript runs just fine.

Works Fine: oXL.Run("ButtonTest.xlsm!Module1.buttonclick");

GIves Error: oXL.Run("test.xlsm!Module1.makeconfigs");

Full Code of my concept testing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


    <body>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">

</SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JScript"> 
function AutomateExcel(store,direct,MdfFloor,MdfSW,Include)
{

   // Start Excel and get Application object.
      var oXL = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
      var filename = "D:\\Profiles\\ngwx36\\Desktop\\test.xlsm"; 
      oXL.Visible = true;

   // Open Staging Workbook
      var oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add(filename);


   // Place vars from input in correct cell
      oWB.Sheets("Instructions").Cells(1, 5).Value = store;
      oWB.Sheets("Instructions").Cells(2,5).Value = direct;
      oWB.Sheets("SWInventory").Cells(3,2).Value = MdfFloor;
      oWB.Sheets("SWInventory").Cells(3,6).Value = MdfSW;

   //checks to see if 3rd MDF needs to be included
      if (Include == "Yes"){
        oWB.Sheets("SWInventory").Cells(5,2).Value = "Included";
      }

   //fill 2 IDFs in to test atm
      oWB.Sheets("SWInventory").Cells(7,2).Value = "1";
      oWB.Sheets("SWInventory").Cells(7,3).Value = "1";
      oWB.Sheets("SWInventory").Cells(7,4).Value = "SW01";
      oWB.Sheets("SWInventory").Cells(7,6).Value = "EX2200C";
      oWB.Sheets("SWInventory").Cells(8,2).Value = "2";
      oWB.Sheets("SWInventory").Cells(8,3).Value = "2";
      oWB.Sheets("SWInventory").Cells(8,4).Value = "SW02";
      oWB.Sheets("SWInventory").Cells(8,6).Value = "EX2200C";

      window.alert("Filled Sheet Just Fine");
      //run config macro
      oXL.Run("test.xlsm!Module1.makeconfigs");
      window.alert("Process Complete");





}

</SCRIPT>
<Form Name=Input>
<p>
          <label>Store Name</label>
          <input type = "text"
                 name= "StoreName"
                 value = "" />
</p>
<p>
          <label>File Directory</label>
          <input type = "text"
                 name= "FilePath"
                 value = "" />
</p>
<p>
          <label>MDF Floor #</label>
          <input type = "text"
                 name= "MdfFloor"
                 value = "" />
</p>
<p>
          <label>MDF Type</label>
          <input type = "text"
                 name= "MdfType"
                 value = "Enter MDF SW TYpe" />
</p>
<p>
          <label>MDF Include</label>
          <input type = "text"
                 name= "MdfInc"
                 value = "3rd MDF Yes or No?" />
</p>

</form>
<P><INPUT id=button1 type=button value="Start Excel" 
          onclick="AutomateExcel Input.StoreName.Value,Input.FilePath.Value,Input.MdfFloor.Value,Input.MdfType.value,Input.MdfInc.Value">
</P>    

</body>
</html>
```

Update:

I haven't found out why I get the expected error, but I did implement a workaround fix by making a VBScript function that simply runs the macro. For some reason VB can run this specific macro but Jscript doesnt like to.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <script language = "VBscript">
         function RunMacro()
            dim oXL
            Set oXL = GetObject(,"Excel.Application")
            oXL.Run "makeconfigs"
         end function
        </script>
        <Script Language = "jscript">
         function AutomateExcel(){
            var oXL = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
            var filename = "D:\\Profiles\\ngwx36\\Desktop\\test.xlsm"; 
            oXL.Visible = true;

            var oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add(filename);
            RunMacro();

         }
        </Script>

        <P><INPUT id=button1 type=button value="Start Excel" 
          onclick="AutomateExcel()">
</P>    

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: just some more info. I removed the 2 alert messages since they were just there for err checking. I also commented out the run macro and everything works fine. It opens the excel doc, inputs the correct data  to the correct fields, and turns over control to me. I can then manually run the macro and it works fine. So it is definitely something about the run macro line it doesnt like :\

Comment: I think it has to do with the excel workbook somehow. a simple script to just open a workbook and run a macro doesn't even work. Yet if I just simply change the workbook it opens and the macro it runs, the code works fine. Could it be caused by the excel macro being written in VBScript?

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of error code collision.

The JavaScript Engine maps 1004 to*Syntax Errors: expected ';'*, see [JavaScript Syntax Errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/6bby3x2e%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

Office Automation maps code 1004 to *Run-time Error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error*

If you make a call to an Office component (in your case Excel.Application) form JavaScript, a Run-time Error 1004 occurring in the component gets propagates to the JavaScript engine, which maps this code to a Syntax Errors: expected ';'.

Of course this type of error propagation is downright silly, thanks Microsoft.

So your problem is not with the JavaScript, but inside a call to an Office component, presumably the run() method.

Answer (score 0):

The only line I see that is missing a semi-colon is your call to `window.alert()`:

```
window.alert("Filled Sheet Just Fine")
```

Just add it back and I'm guessing you'll be fine.

Comment: I have one there already. Just didnt copy it over for some reason. Even with a semi colon after the expected error still happens.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a semicolon at the end of this line:

```
window.alert("Filled Sheet Just Fine")
```

Comment: Yeah that was just a copy/paste typo somehow. Even with the smi-colon after that alert I am still getting the error :\

Answer (score 0):

Looks like JScript is handling the `onclick`. Its syntax works with VBScript, but not with JScript. This can be fixed by adding a pseudo protocol:

```
onclick="VBScript: AutomateExcel Input.StoreName.Value, Input.FilePath.Value, ... "
      JScript expects ; here ---^
```

You can also use JScript, but then you need to enclose the arguments of `AutomateExcel()` to parenthesis, though I'm not sure if `Input` is defined for Jscript.

It's unclear to me, why an online event handler is sometimes interpreted with VBScript and sometimes with JScript. Maybe you want to ask a new question about this.

Comment: Still doesn't fix the issue :\. If I remove the oXL.run() line the script functions perfectly. As for the AutomateExcel() call on the button click, I was using () around it first but as soon as I went from 1 passed var to multiple it quit working. Digging around seems Jscript likes () for 1 var but just an open list for multiple? I dunno maybe it uses JScript for 1 but has to revert to VB for multiple? I have no idea. All I know is I am still getting a ; Expected on the line corresponding to my macro run line. Thanks everyone for help so far.

Comment: I found out the correct syntax for multiple var passing in JScript, and what had happened is frustrasted by a error related to () when calling a sub, I inadvertently switched it to VBScript (which solved the problem). I added the pseudo protocol just to be safe, but honestly I tried both VB and correct J script formats without the excel macro run and both work just fine. The expected error only happens when I add back in the macro command.

Comment: Hmm... I was sure that `onclick` was "guilty", but no... Also it looks like you didn't actually need the pseudo protocol. It's just something which gets HTAs going mad, if a program has both script types. I'm sorry if my answer wasn't helpful...

Answer (score 0):

//This works fine for me.

```
       function call_Macro(){
        try{
        var ExApp;
        var excel_file;
        ExApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
        var excel_file = ExApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\\NewFolder\\FSO.xlsm"); 

        ExApp.Run("FSO.xlsm!MacroName");

        excel_file.Close();    // important
        excel_file = null;
        ExApp.Quit();
        ExApp = null;       
        }
        catch(ex)
        {
        alert(ex.message);
        excel_file.Close();    // important
        excel_file = null;
        ExApp.Quit();
        ExApp = null;   
        }
    }
```